# Elastic Search 6.4.2 combine fuzziness search with exact search

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, search

A project at Laravel, more detailed : for `Laravel Nova` searching.
I have a model rules in `ES` for finding a specific `Model` records. It has the following rules

```
namespace App\Elastic\Rules;

use ScoutElastic\SearchRule;

class BusinessSearch extends SearchRule

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function buildHighlightPayload()
{
    return [
        'fields' => [
            'name' => [
                'type' => 'plain'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function buildQueryPayload()
{
    $query = $this->builder->query;

    return [
        'should' => [
            [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query'     => $query,
                    'fuzziness' => 5
                ]
            ],
            [
                'nested' => [
                    'path' => 'categories',
                    'query' => [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                'match' => [
                                    'categories.name' => $query
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

I need somehow to add to this functionality the following : 
When user types a value in quotes, it must perform a `exact search`, otherwise, `fuzziness` like now. Any ideas about implementing that stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having what query to be executed depending on what input user would provide for this scenario, I have created the below generic query and I suppose that would suffice your requirements.

```
POST testindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "must":{  
                     "multi_match":{  
                        "query":"something",
                        "fields":[ "field_1", "field_2" ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "must":{  
                     "multi_match":{  
                        "query":"something",
                        "fields":[  "field_1", "field_2" ],
                        "fuzziness": 5
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

For simplicity, the above query would be something like the below

```
bool:
  should:
    bool:
    - must [ exact query ]
    bool:
    - must [ fuzzy query ]
```

Both the queries would be executed for all inputs, however if the `exact query` doesn't give you results, the `fuzzy query` would return you the results.

Now if `exact query` does return results, `fuzzy query` may also give you results, except that then the results that are hit by `exact query` would end up having higher `relevancy` or `_score` and therefore would show up in the top of the search result.

Let me know if that helps!